# Можно ли открыть URL в стандартном браузере с помощью POCO C++?

Tags: c++, oauth2, poco

Необходимо авторизовать приложение пользователем по протоколу OAuth2, а затем получить token отображенный на странице-ответе в браузере. У самой Poco сэмплы довольно скудные. Проблем с получением bearer-token возникнуть не должно, а вот авторизация через браузер - уже проблема.

Повторюсь: Можно ли открыть URL в стандартном браузере с помощью POCO C++ или нужно каким-нибудь другим образом подойти к этой проблеме?

```
  Poco::URI uri( _uri + "/oauth2/authorize" );

  uri.addQueryParameter("client_id", _consumerKey);
  uri.addQueryParameter("response_type","code"); 
  //как вызвать в браузере?

  //Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
  //Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, uri, Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```

Comment: `ShellExecute(0, 0, L"http://www.google.com", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW );` правда хз при чем тут поко)

Comment: Ну да, это чисто winapi)